# actualizar un solo registro con submit en index.html y funcion en views.py

Tags: python, html5, django

Tengo un código el cual me debería permitir actualizar el campo = estado, por 'entregado' este es el index.html donde se encuentra el boton:

```
<form action="/some/url/mapped/to/pedido_sub/view/">
      <input type="submit" name="Aprobar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Aprobar"/>
</form>
```

luego el codigo de views.py es este:

```
def pedido_sub(request, id_pedido):

    pedido = get_object_or_404(Pedido, pk=id_pedido)
    if (request.method == POST) and ("Aprobar" in request.POST):
        pedido.estado = 'entregado'
        pedido.save()
        # Send a Success Message to the User
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

a idea es que al pulsar el botón me actualice el campo, pero el error es:

```
Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/some/url/mapped/to/pedido_sub/view/?Aprobar=Aprobar
```

Mi urls.py de la app:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^home', login_required(Pedidoapp.views.home), name='home'), 
    url(r'^confirmar/',login_required(Pedidoapp.views.aprobar_pedido), name='aprobar_pedido'),
    url(r'^Pedido/$', login_required(Pedidoapp.views.add), name="add"),
```

Mi urls.py del proyecto:

```
urlpatterns = [ # Examples: 
    url(r'^home/', include(Pedidoapp.urls, namespace="usuario")),
    url(r'^home/$', login_required(Pedidoapp.views.home), name="home"), 
    # url(r'^home_user/$', login_required(Pedidoapp.views.homeuser), name="homeuser"), 
    url(r'^add/$', login_required(Pedidoapp.views.add), name="add"), url(r'aprobar_pedido/$', aprobar_pedido, name='aprobar_pedido'),
```

Comment: Debes añadir tu vista a tus urls

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás confundiendo varios conceptos de Django:

1)- El formulario está dirigiendo hacia una ruta (`/some/url/mapped/to/pedido_sub/view/`) que no está especificada en `urls.py` de la app. Deberías agregar la siguiente línea (**notar que cambié `/some/url/mapped/to/pedido_sub/view/` por `/pedido_sub/` por cuestión de simpleza para el ejemplo**):

```
 url(r'^pedido_sub/(?P<id_pedido>\d+)/$', Pedidoapp.pedido_sub , name="pedido_sub"),
```

Ahí le estoy diciendo que después de la dirección `pedido_sub/` va a venir un numero. Y el html del form quedaría:

```
<form action="{% url 'pedido_sub' variable %}" method="GET">
      <input type="submit" name="Aprobar" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Aprobar"/>
</form>
```

Nótese que se puede usar el `name` declarado en `urls.py` para hacer el código más mantenible en el caso de que en un futuro quieras cambiar la url sin tener que modificar todas las rutas en tus HTMLs.

2)- Para poder utilizar el `id_pedido` que estás recibiendo por parámetro en `pedido_sub(request, id_pedido)` tendrías que enviar el id por la URL, por ejemplo:

```
localhost/miPagina/pedido_sub/4783/
```

Siendo `4783` el id_pedido. Como mencioné arriba se puede hacer:

```
<form action="{% url 'pedido_sub' id_pedido %}" method="GET">
```

Siendo id_pedido una variable de Django.

3)- Y por ultimo deberías tomar el `request.GET` en vez de `request.POST` ya que no parece ser información sensible la que estás enviando y te ahorra hacer uso del CSRF Token:

```
def pedido_sub(request, id_pedido):

    pedido = get_object_or_404(Pedido, pk=id_pedido)
    if (request.method == GET) and ("Aprobar" in request.GET):
        pedido.estado = 'entregado'
        pedido.save()
        # Send a Success Message to the User
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Espero haberte ayudado! Cualquier cosa nos avisas!

Saludos!

Comment: Estimado! gracias por los conocimientos, ahora bien al probar aquellas sugerencias aparte de que el codigo mejoro y se simplifico, los errores al ingresar al home es:  Reverse for 'pedido_sub' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []. Donde marca en rojo: <form action="{% url 'pedido_sub' id_pedido %}" method="GET">

Comment: o cuando escribo la url con el id al final me manda esto: NameError at /home/aprobar/11/
name 'GET' is not defined. deje igual como me a sugerido solo cambie el nombre de la url: url(r'^aprobar/(?P<id_pedido>\d+)/$', Pedidoapp.views.pedido_sub , name="pedido_sub"), ayuda porfavor!

Comment: Hola! El primer error se da porque te dice que la variable id_pedido está vacía y te dice que la URL /pedido_sub/ necesita un número después y nada se le está dando. Si querés que el número no sea obligatorio agrega a tu urls.py `url(r'^pedido_sub/$', Pedidoapp.pedido_sub , name="pedido_sub"),` o podrías probar cambiando el que tienes por `url(r'^pedido_sub/(?P<id_pedido>\d*)/$', Pedidoapp.pedido_sub , name="pedido_sub"),` con `d*` decimos que es opcional, pero nunca lo probé

Comment: En cuanto al segundo error no tengo idea, estoy desde el celular, en cuanto esté en la compu me fijo y si encuentro algo te aviso!

Comment: gracias por su atención en este asunto colega! me a servido mucho, me entra el home y la lista de pedidos, ahora solo tengo un error cuando al darle al boton "aprobar" a un pedido el cual le cree un confirmar.html con el boton aceptar y cancelar, no llega a ese html y sale esto: ValueError at /home/aprobar//
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' y la url q muestra es: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/aprobar//?Aprobar=Aprobar, debería salir el id del pedido despues de aprobar/ no lo cree? podria ayudarme con esto estimado? gracias

Comment: De nada colega! Para eso estamos! Sisi, estas en lo correcto, tendría que salir el numero entre esos `//` así que habría que fijarse que el nombre de la variable id_pedido este bien escrito o su asignación sea correcta, porque al parecer no existe o su valor es nulo